# Listview layout with different buttons

Tags: listview, layout

I need some help to make listview layout , main problem is that first and last buttons is different than all other and list can have different number of buttons. How can I identify first and last listview items and set them buttons other than all other listview buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can set buttons properties in layout xml of your Android Application, all elements have their unique id and name, you can identify them by those properties, if you are adding elements in runtime, there are methods to set this values.

```
Button btn = new Button(Context);
btn.setId(1); //seting id
//setting layout behavior
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
btn.setText("Dynamic button");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing listview using a loop then add one class for first and last **li** tag.

Then you can change the buttons of list through css:

```
li.first {
  list-style: disc outside url("http://mintmiles.com/admail/stcccfb13/images/bullet.gif");
}
li.last {
  list-style: disc outside url("http://www.plussizeliving.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/bullet-style.jpg");
}
```